# Getting string representations from a hashtable using a toString

Tags: java, hashmap, tostring

Just wondering what the best way to represent Strings are from Hash tables, I figured you would use an iterator somehow in a toString method but wasn't sure.

It should look something like the following

```
{5/10 = 3/9}
to
{true@5/10}@3/9
```

So far I have ( i know this doesn't use an iterator, since i wasn't really sure how to use it in this regard)

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    for (Map.Entry<BigFraction, BigFraction> entry : knowledgeD.entrySet()) {
        BigFraction key = entry.getKey();
        BigFraction value = entry.getValue();
```

where bigfraction is just a fraction datatype, replace it with whatever  you want

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the following may work, I believe

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myTable.entrySet())
    {
        builder.append(entry.getKey());
        builder.append("=>");
        builder.append(entry.getValue());
        builder.append("\n");
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: if you use a `StringBuilder` you shouldn't use the operator `+` to concatenate strings

Comment: Do you know how to use an iterator to order the first value from smallest to largest?

Comment: you should use either TreeMap or SortedMap because these guys support a natural or custom order and HashMap doesn't. In addition, you should read about Comparator right here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: I have used a tree map in my iterator method actually which sorts my keys, I cant work out how to call it though, it just call with my .iterator() however since that's the way i set it up.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see exact toString() representation, you can open the HashTable class and have a look at the toString() method.

This is directly from JDK,

```
public synchronized String toString() {
    int max = size() - 1;
    if (max == -1)
        return "{}";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> it = entrySet().iterator();

    sb.append('{');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        Map.Entry<K,V> e = it.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            sb.append(key   == this ? "(this Map)" : key.toString());
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(value == this ? "(this Map)" : value.toString());

        if (i == max)
        return sb.append('}').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    }
```

Comment: there is no sense to make it synchronized

Comment: I'd like to get this first values in order, I can see you have used an iterator but as for the sync, I can't work out why you need to use that, any idea how to get them in order or rising first values e.g  the true@s

Comment: @CyrilDeba as I said this is directly from the toString method of HashTable. in HashTable all methods are thread safe, that's it. In your expected o/p {true@5/10}@3/9.  5/10 is key, 3/9 is value, what is true here?